# I want to select a table when doing an update query but I get error code 1093

Tags: sql, mysql-workbench

I wrote the query below where I want to change the price of title 1001 to the price of the most recently published book. However, I kept getting an error and I have been trying to find a way to work around the error since I know I get the error because I can't modify the same table which you use in the select part.

SQL query:

```
update titles 
set price = (select price from titles where pubDate = (select max(pubdate) from titles)) 
where titleID = 1001
```

Error Code: 1093. You can't specify target table 'titles' for update in FROM clause

titles table has titleID, title, pubID, subId, pubDate, cover, and price columns.

Does anyone know another way to do this update query?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a transaction block.

Simulating the error:

```
   MySQL> create table testUpdate(no int, txt varchar(20));
   Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.04 sec)
   MySQL [re_ram]> insert into testUpdate values(1,'one');
   Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
   MySQL > insert into testUpdate values(2,'two');
   Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)
   MySQL > insert into testUpdate values(3,'three');
   Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)
   MySQL > insert into testUpdate values(4,'four');
   Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)
   MySQL > insert into testUpdate values(5,'five');
   Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)
   MySQL > select * from testUpdate;
   +------+-------+
   | no   | txt   |
   +------+-------+
   |    1 | one   |
   |    2 | two   |
   |    3 | three |
   |    4 | four  |
   |    5 | five  |
   +------+-------+
   5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
   MySQL > update testUpdate set txt=(select txt from testUpdate where no=(. elect min(no) from testUpdate)) where no=5;
ERROR 1093 (HY000): You can't specify target table 'testUpdate' for update 
 in FROM clause
```

The fix is to use a transaction block:

```
 start transaction;
select txt into @txt from testUpdate where no=(select min(no) from testUpdate);
update testUpdate set txt=@txt where no=5;
commit;
```

Output:

```
   MySQL > start transaction;
   Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.05 sec)
   MySQL > select txt into @txt from testUpdate where no=(select min(no) from testUpdate);
   Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
   MySQL > update testUpdate set txt=@txt where no=5;
   Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
   Rows matched: 1  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0
   MySQL > commit;
   Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```